# Qual a diferença do npm i -g create-next-app para npx create-next-app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

Criei um projeto Next.js e no terminal apareceu o seguinte:

> ```
> A new version of create-next-app is available!
>
>
> You can update by running: npm i -g create-next-app
> ```

Qual a diferença e qual é o mais recomendado?

Answer (score 1):

Não existe "diferença". São comandos diferentes, de modo que têm funções diferentes. Portanto não faz sentido perguntar quais as diferenças e qual é mais recomendado. Os dois são igualmente recomendados, só que para funções diferentes.

- O `npm i -g create-next-app` instala uma nova versão do programa `create-next-app`.
- Já o `npx create-next-app` é utilizado para rodar, de forma propriamente dita, o programa `create-next-app` para criar uma nova aplicação Next.

Você pode verificar a diferença entre versões do `create-next-app` na página de [*releases* do GitHub do projeto em questão](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v10.0.5).

Saiba mais sobre o `npx` [aqui](https://github.com/npm/npx).